How to render table from react-markdown with react-typed
I have a react component which gets a message and renders it with react-typed and react-markdown.
This is an example from the code:
<ReactTyped
    showCursor={false}
    strings={[
        ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
            <Markdown
                 className="markdown"
                 remarkPlugins={[
                     remarkGfm
                 ]}
            >
                {message}
            </Markdown>
        )
    ]}
    typeSpeed={10}
    stopped={stopAnimation}
 />

The message can contain a table, which markdown renders perfectly, however with the react-typed it gets a little messy and it renders each column one by one. So is there a way to render columns for each row at once?
